Why is the target not injured more severely in the fish market fight scene in Ip Man?



In this video, at 6:31, Ip Man is depicted striking a man with two cleavers in his hands. However, the cleavers do not actually injure the person; instead, they merely beat him.
A close-up shot shows that the sharp edge of the cleaver is in the correct position to cut:

So,

Why didn't the cleaver cut?
What was the purpose of striking with the cleaver if it wasn't cutting or stabbing the person?


Despite the still shot, if you look at 6:10 he clearly reverses the cleavers to use the blunt edges. Either the shot with the blade against the neck is a mistake or he temporarily reversed that blade again to show a threat to the leader of the enemies. He could be showing the leader that he could have just killed him but chose not to.
Hitting someone with a blunt piece of metal that doesn't cut hurts a lot more than hitting with a fist, and it also prevents injury to your fists.
